# Icinga output Plugin for Logstash causing OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError:certificate verify failed Issue

Tags: ssl, logstash, monitoring, icinga, icinga2

Hi I have installed logstash plugin for Icinga 2. I have setup the API by issuing `icinga2 api setup` and then restarted the Icinga 2 service.

I am using Icinga 2 API username and password available in /etc/icinga2/conf.d/api-users.conf and try to push few logs to Icinga 2 from Logstash and getting the following issue

```
[2017-10-04T07:14:14,565][ERROR][logstash.outputs.icinga  ] Request failed {:host=>"xxxxxxxxxx", :port=>5665, :path=>"/v1/actions/process-check-result?service=%25%7Bhostname%7D%21dummy", :body=>"{\"plugin_output\":\"83.149.9.216 - - [04/Jan/2015:05:13:42 +0000] \\\"GET /presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/images/Test-search.png HTTP/1.1\\\" 200 203023 \\\"http://semicomplete.com/presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/\\\" \\\"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.77 Safari/537.36\\\"\"}", :error=>#<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: certificate verify failed>}
```

Here is my configuration file

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/home/logstashtest/*"
        start_position => beginning
        ignore_older => 0
    }
}
filter {
    if ([message] !~ "83.149.9.216") {
        drop { }
    }
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}"}
    }
}
output {
      icinga {
        host           => "*****" //Remote Icinga Host
        user           => "*****" //Icinga 2 Api User
        password       => "*****" //Icinga 2 Api Password
        action         => "process-check-result"
        action_config  => {
          plugin_output => "%{message}"
        }
        icinga_host    => "%{hostname}"
        icinga_service => "dummy"

      }
}
```

Do I need to pass the path for SSL certificate in the request available in pki/ca.crt. Is there a way to disable SSL validation in Logstash? Please help me on what is causing the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Icinga output for Logstash plugin by default uses SSL to connect to Icinga API. I have disabled by setting `ssl_verify  => false` in the plugin